# Creating a DialogBar with MFC with my own controls

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc

I'm turning mad with a little problem with Visual Studio 2008 and MFC. I'm working on a project actually and I'm trying to create an SDI Application. Right, now I want to add a dockable DialogBar. Well, the first time I added it with the resource view, I could create the bar without problems. 
But... I want to add some controls like a couple of ListBox, buttons and so on. The program doesn't allows me to create member variables for these controls. The option appears in grey.

Searching a little, I found that it's mandatory to create a new class derived from CDialogBar and "enhance" it with the Message handler and so on. I've been reading some tutorials and it didn't work for me.

Can you please help me? I'm starting to get nervous, the use of dialogbars is mandatory in my design and I've never implemented them before.

Thank you very much, and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a control member variable by hand instead of using the wizard. All it takes is a call to DDX_Control in the dialog bar's DoDataExchange function.

But CDialogBar-derived classes do not handle control clicks. The CDialogBar class forwards all of those messages to the dialog bar's parent window. So be prepared to add the message handlers to the parent (usually CMainFrame).

For learning purposes you might try creating your dialog bar as a CDialog first, to see the proper code lines and message map entries supplied by the wizard. Then you can copy/move these details as appropriate into your actual code project.